# Data Feeders implementation in Gatiling for RESTful webservices load testing

Tags: load-testing, gatling

I am working on implementing Gatling tool to load test few of our RESTful web API methods,
    for some reason I am not successful in parameterize my input data into the URI.

```
I am getting "i.g.h.a.AsyncHandlerActor" error.. 
it would be great if I'm able to see what exactly the end URI where the call was made.

below is my Scala code for one of the method to be load tested

import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom

class StockRun3 extends Simulation {

  val httpConf = http
    .baseURL("http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:95/v9/stk")
    .acceptHeader("application/json")
    .authorizationHeader("appKeyToken=XXXXXXX&appKey=YYYYYYYYYY")

   object Search {  
        val Datafeeder= csv("StockDataSource2.csv").random

        val search = feed(Datafeeder)
            .exec(http("Search")
            .get("/availability")
            .queryParam("""productIds""","""${product}""")
            .queryParam("""ocationIds""","""${store}""")
             )
            .pause(1)
    }

  val users = scenario("Users").exec(Search.search)

  setUp(
    users.inject(nothingFor(4 seconds),
    atOnceUsers(10),
    rampUsers(10) over(60 seconds),
    constantUsersPerSec(2) during(30 seconds))

  ).protocols(httpConf)
  }
```

Comment: The same code works great if I just comment-out the Data feeder part. But if I inlcude the feeder, the HTTP response in the console says its 404, but I need to see where exactly the URI ended wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As [explained in the documentation](http://gatling.io/docs/2.0.3/general/configuration.html#logback-xml), lower the logging level in logback.xml.
Then, you have a typo in "ocationIds" queryParam.